# What is the optimal index for this SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table with 4 columns:
`CREATE TABLE table1 (a BIGSERIAL UNIQUE, b INTEGER, c enum1, d enum2);`

```
a | b | c | d|
¯¯|¯¯ |¯¯ |¯¯
2 | 5 |'x'|'r'  
5 | 1 |'y'|'s'
8 | 12|'z'|'r'
10| 8 |'x'|'t'
    ...
```

The table contains a very large number of rows and I care about the performance of queries of the form:

`SELECT SUM(b) WHERE a > A AND c = C and d = D`.

The enum types `enum1` and `enum2` may take one of only several values (is this relevant?).

Is the optimal index simply:

`CREATE INDEX on table1 (a, c, d)`?

Do I need to specify that the first column is numerical and the later columns in the index are discrete valued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend an index on `(c, d, a)`.

In particularly, the ordering of `c` and `d` doesn't matter in the index, but they should be the *first* two columns, with `a` following them.

The index `(a, c, d)` is not optimal, because the comparison on `a` is an inequality.

Comment: Stupid question, but if I don't create an index then does postgres just naively iterate through the rows in order? Or is there always some index underhood? Maybe the order the columns are specified in at creation?

Comment: @JSStuball . . . If there are no indexes, then Postgres will do a full table scan.

Comment: @JSStuball  Since "a" is declared unique, it must have an index on it.  PostgreSQL will take that index into consideration, just like it does explicitly created ones.